# Connecting 2 users to a mac and run separate GUIs?

Tags: macos

I've been searching for solutions but I'm not sure I've found the correct one.

I have a MBP running El Capitan with 2 user accounts.  I have an old Macbook that I'd like my wife to use but all of her stuff is on the MBP second account.  Can that old Macbook remote into my MBP and log into her account while I am logged into my account (on that MBP)?

Answer (score 0):

After playing around a bit more, I realized that if you enable Screen Sharing and when you go to login on the second machine, if you use the other login, it will give you exactly what I was asking for.